# Expo: How do I bring up the Debug Screen on a live Android device when Im programming for React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, device

I have an Android phone and am debugging a React Native app in Expo.  How do I bring up the debug screen shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Shake the device and it will come up

Answer (score 0):

But from **RN 0.61.5** , that's purely React native, the logs are automatically printed in the terminal where you usually do `react-native start` , so you can try out that if you are using purely react native.